# How to save quality of the text when Windows scaling is higher then 100%?

Tags: delphi, scaling, raster

I've tried Delphi XE7, which is the latest version I have. Put some simple LABEL on it and start it.

If Windows scaling is 125 or 150 % entire text looks smooth, like when you resize raster and not vector.

Delphi use DrawText API call on Canvas. The same thing Microsoft controls do but when I create some simple label in some MS tool I'm not getting this problem.

How to how sharp text on 125 and 150 %? How to force text to draw it as vector, not magnified raster?

Thanks.

Comment: 'smooth' generally is a good thing, but I suspect you mean it looks bad. Perhaps 'pixellated' is a better word?

Comment: What ever you call it, it looks resized and not clean and sharped. Even when I start Delphi XE7 it looks ugly. I've tried to start some different apps under 150% and most of them looks normal.

Comment: Presumably this is simply that your app is subject to DPI virtualization. Read up on that subject. Add the system DPI aware setting to your manifest. Set Scaled to True on all your forms. Supply and use larger glyphs for your toolbar buttons.

Comment: David, I saw your post regarding DPI manifest but I didn't know how to add it to my Delphi 2007 application. Could you please help me with this? Can I force app somehow not to resize on high DPI?

Comment: Or you could use a larger font. I've once create a scalable label. You can have the source code for that, but is based on a cxLabel from DevExpress you'll have to "port" it to a standard label you self.

Comment: You just need to add the appropriate  manifest. It's just a resource. It's been covered so any times here. No need for us to repeat the details.

Comment: This is definitely a case where you need to attach a screenshot. If you don't have enough rep to add one in your question, upload it to imgur and edit your question to include a link. Include what you get at 100% and at 150%, and a picture of what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

I see comments but no answer.  This is the answer:

You need to provide a declaration of dpi-awareness in your manifest to avoid DPI virtualization.  But once you do so, you need to be sure your application properly handles the DPI.

Here is most of the information you would need:
http://news.helpandmanual.com/2014/11/a-delphi-developers-guide-for-4k-displays/